# Mint opening wrong login screen sometimes

Tags: linux-mint, themes, login-screen

I've created my own login screen editing the code of `Zukitwo-Circle`. It works perfectly, but sometimes, instead of opening it, Mint simply opens `GTK`, the pure GTK, with no theme. Sometimes that happens on startup and sometimes after a logoff. How can I fix that?

Just has a reference, I've changed `Zukitwo-Circle`'s `index.html` to:

> https://github.com/vitor251093/autoMint/blob/master/Image/index.html

And have inserted at `/etc/checkWeb.sh` with that crontab: `*/1 * * * * root /etc/checkWeb.sh`:

> https://github.com/vitor251093/autoMint/blob/master/Image/checkWeb.sh

There are also pictures, which I haven't time to upload yet.

Comment: Somewhat confused: GTK is not a program - it's a library to develop programs. Do you mean Gnome? Or do you mean the GTK theme?

Comment: GTK theme, but it calls itself "the pure GTK" in it's description.

Answer (score 0):

> GTK theme, but it calls itself "the pure GTK" in it's description.

Ah... I see.

I've had a weird problem with themes not long ago. It might be related somehow. Because of a configuration error, there were actually two themes active at the same time. This is acceptable by CSS' cascading standards, so it does not produce any execution error. But the result was quite ugly, because some of the CSS rules of the second were incompatible with the first.

Could it be that your login is loading one theme before another sometimes?

EDIT: I went to search for a description of the problem I had, and found [I had even documented it on my page](http://www.jcoppens.com/soft/howto/gtk/flatstudio.en.php). Memory problems :) The issue in my case was that The theme I choose actually loaded another theme as 'initial state', then modified parts to customize it. I was suspecting that in your case, doing this at the login phase might cause (access) problem.

Did you try *not* changing the theme in the login but doing it later (just to test)?

Comment: Everything is possible. How two themes can be active at the same time? Note that my `/etc/mdm/mdm.conf` file in configured correctly. Do you think it might be set on `/usr/share/mdm/defaults.conf`?

Comment: Edited the reply.

Comment: I don't know if it has some relation. In my case it wasn't a merge of two themes, but a replacement. I've checked `/usr/share/mdm/defaults.conf` after your message and I think the problem might be there.

Comment: What do you mean _changing the theme in the login_? The computer its set up to start with that theme, loading that from `/etc/mdm/mdm.conf`.